# How Do I Keep HttpSessions Alive in Tomcat?

Tags: session, tomcat, servlets, tomcat6, httpsession

I'm having a bit of trouble with Session timeouts in my Tomcat served web application. From reading over Tomcat's documentation, sessions expire after a time which can be configured in the web.xml file.

```
<session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

Quesion) Does this mean 30 minutes from when the session was created for the user? Or 30 minutes from when the session was last accessed?

If it is, as I originally thought, 30 minutes from when the session was last accessed, I don't seem to be seeing this behavior. My sessions seem to be lost as I'm using the site. Are there any other ways to configure session behavior besides this one setting? Is there something I'm missing?

Apache Tomcat/6.0.20

Comment: Related: [Java Servlet instantiation and session variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/java-servlet-instantiation-and-session-variables).

Answer (score 7):

A session is started for the web browser when it connects to your application. Tomcat closes the session on the server when the maximum period of inactivity has passed (30 minutes).

This timeout is reset whenever there is activity on the web browser, such as refreshing the current page or navigating through other pages under the application control. Merely keeping a browser window open does not keep the session open because it does not generate any activity on the browser.

You can set it in the web.xml file as you described.

You can also set it for the `session` object by calling `setMaxInactiveInterval(int interval)`
This specifies the time, in seconds, between client requests before the servlet container will invalidate this session.

You have to make sure, that the **cookies** are **enabled** for your browser. Otherwise you create a new Session with each request. You should call the `HttpServletResponse.encodeURL(String url)` for each URL in your application. From the api doc:

*"Encodes the specified URL by including the session ID in it, or, if encoding is not needed, returns the URL unchanged. The implementation of this method includes the logic to determine whether the session ID needs to be encoded in the URL. For example, if the browser supports cookies, or session tracking is turned off, URL encoding is unnecessary.*

*For robust session tracking, all URLs emitted by a servlet should be run through this method. Otherwise, URL rewriting cannot be used with browsers which do not support cookies."*